# Root route is not being recognized

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm having a problem where one of the routes fails silently with a 404 error.

app.ts

```js
import * as express from 'express';
import * as rateLimit from 'express-rate-limit';
import * as helmet from 'helmet';
import * as xss from 'xss-clean';
import * as hpp from 'hpp';
import * as cors from 'cors';

import { router } from './routes/v1routes';

const app = express();

// Permite requisições de origens diferentes
app.use(cors());

// Seta cabeçalhos HTTP de segurança
app.use(helmet());

// Limita requisições para a mesma API
const limiter = rateLimit({
    max: 150,
    windowMs: 60 * 60 * 1000,
    message: 'Muitas requisições para este IP, por favor, tente de novo em uma hora.'
});
app.use('/api', limiter);

// Saneamento de dados contra XSS (remove código HTML malicioso enviado pelo usuário)
app.use(xss());

// Previne poluição de parâmetros
app.use(hpp());

// Monta as rotas
app.get( "/api/v1", router);

export default app;
```

routes/v1routes.ts

```js
import { Router } from 'express';

export const router = Router();

router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        data: {
            user: 'Test',
            req: {
                path: req.path
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Basically, if I call `http://localhost:3001/api/v1/`, it returns `404` `Cannot GET /api/v1/`; using `http://localhost:3001/api/v1` also give the same results.

If, on the other hand, I instead change the router to listen everything, that is, `router.get("*", async (req, res, next) => {`, it works.

There must be something incredibly simple that I'm failing to pick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
app.use( "/api/v1", router);
```